# Hypothesis search tree

Tags: python-hypothesis

I have a object with many fields. Each field has different range of values. I want to use hypothesis to generate different instances of this object.

Is there a limit to the number of combination of field values Hypothesis can handle?  Or what does the search tree hypothesis creates look like? I don't need all the combinations but I want to make sure that I get a fair number of combinations where I test many different values for each field. I want to make sure Hypothesis is not doing a DFS until it hits the max number of examples to generate

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: don't worry, this is a common use-case and even a naive strategy works very well.

The actual search process used by Hypothesis is complicated (as in, "lead author's PhD topic"), but it's definitely not a depth-first search!  Briefly, it's a uniform distribution layered on a psudeo-random number generator, with a coverage-guided fuzzer biasing that towards less-explored code paths, with strategy-specific heuristics on top of that.

In general, I trust this process to pick good examples far more than I trust my own judgement, or that of anyone without years of experience in QA or testing research!